# LWC javascript Issue: I am trying to assign salesforce id to the map in javascript

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

```
import getCampaignList from '@salesforce/apex/LeadController.getCampaignNames';

   @wire(getCampaignList, {}) campaignLst;  
  get campaignOptions() {
        var returnOptions = [];
        if(this.campaignLst.data){
            this.campaignLst.data.forEach(ele =>{
                returnOptions.push({label:ele.Name , value:ele.Name});
                // alert(ele.id);
               
               // this.map.set(ele.Name, ele.id );//removed in update
ele?.map(({ Name,Id }) => ({ value: Name, label: Id })
                  ); //updated
            }); 
        }
        console.log(JSON.stringify(returnOptions));
        console.log(this.map);
        return returnOptions;
    }
 handleChange(event) {
        if(event.target.name == 'Campaign'){
            this.leadRecord[event.target.name]=map.get(event.target.value); // I need Map[name=> Id] I am very sure there are no duplicate campaign names.
        }else{
            this.leadRecord[event.target.name] = event.target.value;
        }
```

update:

---

```
          
       ele?.map(
                    ({ Name,Id }) => ({ value: Name, label: Id })
                  );
```

---

```
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Campaign> getCampaignNames(){
        List<Campaign> options = new List<Campaign>();
        try {
           options = [SELECT id, Name FROM Campaign];
}
```

I am trying to get add name, ID to a map object. but Id prints as undefined in console why? but I do get the Name.
Any inputs please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. That means that, for a record returned from Apex, it's going to be `Id`, and not `id`.

Also, if you're going to use imperative programming (e.g. `forEach`), you should at least use the correct function for the job, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
get campaignOptions() {
  return this.campaignLst.data?.map(
    ({ Id, Name }) => ({ value: Id, label: Name })
  );
}
```

Where:

- `?.` means "access this property only if it is not null and not undefined"
- `(...) => (...)` is an arrow function that returns a value
- As a parameter to a function (the left-hand side of our arrow function), `{ x, y }` splits one parameter into its parts, here `Id` and `Name`
- On the other side, for the return value, we assign the value and label

Side note: I recommend using the `Id` for the value to make sure you select the correct record if there are multiple campaigns with the same name. You may want to present additional information to help users disambiguate duplicate names somehow.

Comment: Component error occurred: Id is not defined.

Comment: @Mentee Please edit your question to show your new code, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: I added an update. it is not working some js error but new one. I am very bad at js

Comment: @Mentee No worries. We were all bad at programming at some point. Let me check out your code real quick.

Comment: @Mentee `map=getcampaignMap();` is incorrect. It shouldn't be there. Change your `get campaignOptions` function to look exactly like mine, without changing anything else.

Comment: I changed code . please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140056/discussion-between-mentee-and-sfdcfox).